# Does Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 support mix of nodes with both Intel and AMD processors?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

Is it possible to simultaneously have nodes that run on x86_64 CPUs from different vendors in Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2012R2?

Will Hyper-V allow me to add new node with CPU from AMD if all my previous nodes are on Intel?

Can I have one node on x86_64 Intel CPU and another node on x86_64 AMD CPU?

If yes, can I move virtual machine from one node to another in this scenario? Are there any limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to a Hyper-V Failover Cluster:

> Is it possible to simultaneously have nodes that run on x86_64 CPUs
> from different vendors in Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2012R2?

Yes

> Will Hyper-V allow me to add new node with CPU from AMD if all my
> previous nodes are on Intel?

Yes

> Can I have one node on x86_64 Intel CPU and another node on x86_64 AMD
> CPU?

Yes

> If yes, can I move virtual machine from one node to another in this
> scenario?

Yes

> Are there any limitations?

Yes

Comment: and by limitations you mean no live migration of VMs between nodes, right?

Comment: Yes. You have to shut the VM down to migrate it.